# didFailWithError: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)" on ios8 device NOT simulator

Tags: ipad, ios8

I'm getting my correct coordinates with my iOS8 code for first few times but after about a minute or some seconds i start to get this error:

```
didFailWithError: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)"
```

I'm debugging on my iPad not my simulator.

Does anyone have same problem ?

```
    if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER){
        NSUInteger code = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];
        if (code == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined && ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)] || [locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])) {
            // choose one request according to your business.
            if([[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription"]){
                [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
            } else if([[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription"]) {
                [locationManager  requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Info.plist does not contain NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription or NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription");
            }
        }
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
    {
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        currX = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        currY = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];

    }
}
```

Comment: Got solution? I am facing the same issue. please share if you have solved the issue

Comment: no solution?? Not on simulator here either